# How can i make certain Oracle Table Rows marked as 'historical' invisible/un-available?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a huge existing Order Management Application.

Now, in the main ORDER Table, i am adding a new column: IS_HISTORICAL. If its value is: TRUE, means the Order is Historical now, and should not show up in application.

Now, i have to modify many SQL Queries in my existing application so that they select only those orders whose IS_HISTORICAL is 'FALSE' - i.e add following in WHERE clause:

```
  AND IS_HISTORICAL='FALSE'
```

**Question:** *Is there a easier way - so that i do not have to modify so many application queries (to hide away historical orders)?
Essentially all ORDERS marked as IS_HISTORICAL='TRUE' should become invisible/un-available for read/updates!!*

***Note:*** Right now the table sizes are not very huge, but ultimately i intend to partition the table by IS_HISTORICAL true/false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only going to use the historical data for analysis then I prefer Florin's solution as the amount of data you need to look at for each query remains smaller. It makes the analysis queries more difficult as you need to UNION ALL but everything else will run "quicker" (it may not be noticable).

If some applications/users require access to the historical data the better solution would be to rename your table and create a view on top of it with the query that you need.

The problem with re-writing all your queries is that you're going to forget one or get one incorrect, either now or in the future. A view removes that problem for you as the query is static, every time you query the view the additional conditions you require are automatically added.

Something like:

```
rename orders to order_history;

create or replace view orders as
  select *
    from order_history
   where is_historical = 'FALSE';
```

Two further points.

1. I wouldn't bother with `TRUE` / `FALSE`, if the table gets large it's a lot of additional data to scan. Create your column as a VARCHAR2(1) and use `T` / `F` or `Y` / `N`, they are as immediately obvious but are smaller. Alternatively use a NUMBER(1,0) and `1` / `0`.
2. Don't forget to put a constraint on your table so that the IS_HISTORICAL column can only have the values you've chosen.

   If you're only ever going to have the two values then you may want to consider a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CNCPT1660):

   ```
   alter table order_history 
     add constraint chk_order_history_historical
   check ( is_historical in ('T','F') );
   ```

   Otherwise, maybe you should do this anyway, use a [FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/datainte.htm#CNCPT1649). Define an extra table, ORDER_HISTORY_TYPES

   ```
   create table order_history_types ( 
        id varchar2(1)
      , description varchar2(4000)
      , constraint pk_order_history_types primary key (id)
        );
   ```

   Fill it with your values and then add the foreign key:

   ```
   alter table order_history 
      add constraint fk_order_history_historical
   foreign key (is_historical)
   references order_history_types (id)
   ```

Comment: Maybe, don't put a `select *`, just select the column, we don't care about the `is_historical`

Comment: You should select everything _but_ the column not cared about @Plouf. As I don't know anything about the table I didn't write it. It's not really relevant anyway. The columns selected in the view is irrelevant as long as each query on the view doesn't select every column.

Comment: Ben> I do not need the historical data for analysis at all, i just need to HIDE those Orders. If i create _HIST Table, i will need to create 200 plus of them for Child Tables as well as their data will have to be moved out first (to take care of constraints etc)

Comment: No @Jasper. That's the point of the views, you do _not_ need to move any data at all.... You can dynamically create the SQL statements to do this for all tables in 3 seconds on the USER_* views. The fact that you feel the need to say that's you've got constraints because of the number of tables in the comments indicates that it's relevant information. Please try to put all relevant information in your questions when asking.

Comment: Ben> Do you mean that i rename ALL Tables (Child tables included) and create Views for ALL of them? (Sorry, i should hv mentioned child tables in original question).

Comment: IF that's what you want to do @Jasper, you're the one that said you've _have_ to create 200 tables and I assume you know your schema better than me. From your question I don't see any reason to do so but it depends on what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into using [Virtual Private Database/row-level security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm). This can be used to automatically add the `is_historical = 'FALSE'` predicate when certain conditions are met (e.g. you're connected as the application user).

Comment: Chris> Will this impact performance adversely, since queries are being modified dynamically by DB. Also some of our queries are very complex with several inner joins etc..would that work? Do we need a special license to use Virtual Private Database?

Comment: Any change to a query can make performance better or worse; you'll have to test to find out. This will have the same impact as adding the condition manually though, so it's something you'll need to investigate either way if you're keeping the data in the same table. On the licensing side, I'm not sure.

Comment: For a "soft" delete requirement, this is a good option imo.  A static context should not affect performance really, since its pulling and appending the where clause from memory (other options exist for vpd contexts).

Comment: Some of our Queries are complex eg: with inner joins and so on. Would VPD be able to add the extra where clause at the right place in such queries - i can understand that for simple queries it may work, but what about fairly complex ones. I am unable to test this right away due to permission issues.

Comment: It should be able to add the predicate, but be aware: "For SQL that contains outer join or ANSI operations, some views may not merge and some indexes may not be used. This problem is a known optimization limitation" (from the docs). You'll have to test on your views to see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

If the user only need nonhistorical records, an option is to create an ORDER_HIST table and move there the historical records. (delete and insert)

If some users/applications need both type of records then the partition aproach is the best.

Comment: Florin> Yes i thought of that, but we have 200 plus tables, and i will have to do that _HIST thing for all the tables, as they are all child tables of ORDER in some way - and i cannot move only ORDER Table records away to a _HIST Table, without moving out the children too first(becz of constraints)... Any thoughts?

Comment: Best thing as far I can see is partition the table, then do what Ben recommended: Rename the table and make a view. Constraints won't suffer, child tables does not need rename, the application queries remain the same.